# Are there any implementation of MCAPI API for bare metal (==no OS) system?

Tags: parallel-processing, bare-metal, mcapi

MCA (https://www.multicore-association.org/) created APIs for embedded systems for lightweight communication (in theory its like an MPI, but for embedded systems where resources are scars and maybe there is no OS), but can't find any implementation and I don't really know how could I implement it. Main goal is to achieve parallel computing without an OS, but with an easy to use API. Like OpenMP.

Comment: Sounds like you dont really want baremetal.  Re-asking the question is not how stackoverflow works BTW.  How do you plan to do parallel computing on a single core/threaded microcontroller without a task switcher (basically an operating system)?  Just use a ported RTOS and go from there and/or you have to do this port yourself, including the operating system, the task switcher the api layers into the switcher (the OS).

Comment: Sounds like you have a communication protocol you want and know of an implementation and want to use that.  Need to back up to the communication protocol and work from there with any implementation including roll your own as that sounds to be the goal yes? Not every target can run every high level tool or code.

Comment: are you wanting to parallelize multiple/many microcontrollers or have parallelism on a single mcu?

Comment: if it is the former then where is the master that is the one doing most of the work, and what is the protocol and what is the roadblock to implementing that?

Comment: i want to be able to run a C code on a single MCU with mutliple cores. Obviosly i will need a layer or other codes too to be able the schedule the task and etc, but that would still not be an OS (or am i wrong?). i mean i don't want to run multiple programs and such. i only want a single one run in parallel, which is already achievable on this particular MCU, but with hand written modifications. waking up cores etc. i want this to be automatic so either translate OpenMP run time calls to MTAPI/MPCAPI ones or maybe just wrote a program which automatically modify the program to be parallel.

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/281205205/download this paper about translating OpenMP to MTAPI calls, but not for bare-metal. so i just thinking what would be an optimal way to make a C program with OpenMP directives run on a single, bare-metal, multicore MCU. And it very important there shouldn't be an OS of any kind.

Comment: you are getting very close to an operating system, it is a debate on terminology, but a scheduler with apl calls that dive into that switcher to ask it to do things.  Call it what you will.  What you are going to end up needing to do is take an open source rtos, extract from or learn from them on task switching for that target, make your switcher then build the api on top of that.

Comment: stackoverflow is not here to do google searches for you, if you have a software program that isnt working then post a minimal example, expectations vs actual results.  but sounds like you are a long way from that as development has not started?